# How to solve ClassCastException for java.util.ArrayList via WSDL of ColdFusion 9's CFC?

Tags: apache-flex, wsdl, flash-builder, coldfusion-9, cfc

I hope this problem would not waste your time.

I use Adobe Coldfusion 9 to create CFC to to interact with database. Generally, CFC can be generate WSDL by itself. for example:

```
http://localhost/services/employeeService.cfc?wsdl
```

The WSDL was generated well. But the problem has been found when I tried to use Adobe Flash Builder 4's Data service to generate service class to connect ColdFusion's WSDL.

If you tried to invoked the remote function that return primitive data type as int or String, it works correctly.

```
remote numeric function count() {
    return ormExecuteQuery("select Count(*) from employee")[1];
}
```

[image: With return as primitive type, it works.]

But complex data type such as, return custom class returned with no data in the field.

```
remote fp_sandbox.cfc.employee function get(required numeric id ) {
    return EntityLoad("employee", arguments.id, true);
}
```

[image: Return a complex data type object, but properties is empty.]

For array, if the remote function specified as ColdFusion's Array, it will return an array but with no data in object's property:

```
remote Array function list() {
    return entityLoad("employee", {}, "idEmployee asc");
}
```

[image: If return type is default Array, the children in array has no value in property.]

and if the return type is ORM genarated code, it will throw the exception. It looks like ColdFusion try to cast something.

```
remote fp_sandbox.cfc.employee[] function search(string q ) {
    // query creating.
    return ormExecuteQuery(hqlString, false, params);
}
```

StackTrace:

> InvocationTargetException:There was an error while invoking the
>   operation. Check your operation inputs and try invoking the operation
>   again.

Response Received:

> soapenv:Server.userException
>   coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException:
>   [java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.ArrayList]
>   coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCInvocationException:
>   [java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.ArrayList] at
>   coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFComponentSkeleton.__createCFCInvocationException(CFComponentSkeleton.java:733)
>   at
>   coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFComponentSkeleton.__cast(CFComponentSkeleton.java:409)
>   at
>   fp_sandbox.services.EmployeeService.search(D:\home\cashr.com\wwwroot\fp_sandbox\services\employeeService.cfc)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:388)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:283)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>   at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCProvider.invoke(CFCProvider.java:54) at
>   org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118) at
>   org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83) at
>   org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
>   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281) at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>   at coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doAxisPost(CFCServlet.java:270) at
>   coldfusion.filter.AxisFilter.invoke(AxisFilter.java:43) at
>   coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:356)
>   at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
>   at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>   at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:87) at
>   coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70) at
>   coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>   at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
>   coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.invoke(CFCServlet.java:138) at
>   coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet.doPost(CFCServlet.java:289) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760) at
>   org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853) at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>   at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86) at
>   coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>   at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at
>   com.seefusion.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:49) at
>   com.seefusion.SeeFusion.doFilter(SeeFusion.java:1500) at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at
>   jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101) at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106) at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42) at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>   at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>   at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
>   at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>   at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
>   at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66) ntcps1

Could you give me any suggestion to solve or workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion -- look up the RemoteClass metadata tag... it should point you in the right direction.

Best of luck,
jeremy

Comment: did a quick google search for you: http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2007/10/9/Why-does-ColdFusion-return-a-CFC-to-Flex-as-a-generic-object

Comment: Thank you, jeremy. I will take a look on this point, and will post the result.